# Require Geocoder result to save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

I'm using [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) to get a latitude and longitude for an address. Here's the model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offers


  # Validation
  validates :name, :address, :postcode, :presence => true

  # Geocoding
  geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode

  # Methods
  def full_address
    [address, "London", postcode].compact.join(', ')
  end
end
```

The record is useless without a latitude and longitude so I need to prevent it from saving unless the geocoding is successful.

I tried adding some validations for the address but an address can be valid without being geocodable (e.g. 123 Fake Street, London). I also tried adding validations for the latitude and longitude to be present but because the geocoding takes place after validation that doesn't work either.

To clarify: I'm ideally looking to keep the geocoding after_validation so that I don't have to call geocode for unrelated errors. For example there's a `name` attribute on the model that's required and it doesn't make sense to try and geocode if that's left blank.

Comment: Have you tried using a before_validation callback with the geocode, and then validating the lat/long?

Comment: That works. Ideally I'd like to validate that the address and other fields are ok before I geocode though to save API requests. Will update the question to be clearer about that.

Comment: Have you looked at custom validators? Building your own validator would allow you to control the order in which the validation is done. That is, you can specify that the address is validated before the lat/long. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations